# Can I use button and onclick together

Tags: button, hyperlink, onclick

`<button class="button Play"> <onclick="startgame()";>Start</button>`

What am I doing wrong here, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<button class="button Play" onclick="startgame()">Start</button>
```